# Xubuntu reboots very slow

Tags: xubuntu, reboot

I recently made a fresh Xubuntu 14.04 install. Before that, my laptop was rebooting in approximately 30 seconds, 15 seconds for shutting down and 15 seconds booting again. Now reboot takes about 55 seconds. But booting still takes 15 seconds, problem must be in the shutting down part. I'm using Xubuntu with same configuration for 2 years. Any idea what is wrong with my system?

[EDIT] I recently installed hdapsd, this is the only new package that's different from previous system. And my laptop's configuration: http://pastebin.com/haHGc0JK

Comment: What have you installed since then? Also, what hardware and drivers are you using (use `lspci -v` and add the info to your question via a [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/550110/edit))

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure out what is going on during boot/reboot process is to check boot/reboot messages. If it's not enabled yet then edit '/etc/default/grub' and look for the line that says

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

remove the values 'quiet' and 'splash' and then from the terminal regenerate your grub config like so:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You should be able to see what slows your system down after you reboot your system. Another way to check for boot messages is to check the file '/var/log/boot' or running 'dmesg' command from the terminal.

Comment: I would install bootchart ;-)